# Grub Splash screen on Boot

Tags: 11.04, grub2

I want to enable the nice splash screen on GRUB boot menu. I have Ubuntu 11.04, running on a nVidia graphics card. Please help. I'm new to Linux.

## edit

I want to set a background image when GRUB shows a list of available OS. I have Ubuntu 11.04. I've changed colour through grub.cfg in /boot/grub but can't set an image as background in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it on my own, but the **[Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)** seems to be able to do what you want. It's a nice GUI application where you can easily manage the Grub settings.

[image]