# Empty Grub screen on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I currently have Ubuntu 16.04 (with GNOME 3) installed on my Acer Aspire V Nitro, alongside Windows 10. The installation was fine but when I boot into my system it loads an empty grub screen. For a while I was stuck there but then I was guided by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97620/grub-splash-screen-on-boot). This solved my issue except the last step in the solution, with the `sudo update-grub` command, didn't work.

So basically each time I want to load into either one of my OS's I have to manually go through the solutions in the linked thread.

Is there a better solution to my issue? And why isn't `sudo update-grub` solving my issue?

Edit: `sudo update-grub` outputs the following:

```
Generating grub config file...
Warning: setting grub to non zero timeout value...
Found linux image: path
Found intird image: path
Found windows boot manager: path
adding boot menu entry for EFI Firmware
done
```

Comment: I have updated it to reflect the output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of corruption of grub, you should try to reinstall grub by this command `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` replacing `sda` by your HDD while you are booted into your Operating System. Next run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: I can normally load into my system. I think the issue is that my Grub is unable to locate the configfile and each time boot I have to manually do this using the commands in the linked article.
After booting, I choose to update grub but that doesn't have an effect!

Comment: Nopes, grub is searching for config files from some inexistent directory... Reinstalling GRUB will do

Comment: Do I reinstall grub on my "/" mount point partition

Comment: No, install it on the disk. Do not add any partition number in the above command.